# Which one is the best tool to test a React JS based application?

Tags: automated-testing, tools, test-tools, reactjs, tool-recommend

I am looking for a best tool to test a React JS based application. I want to do end to end test with the tool.
Could you guys please help me to find the best testing tool for React?

Comment: If you're testing end-to-end the fact that your app uses React shouldn't be relevant. There isn't a "best" tool, there are trade-offs that you'll have to make based on your needs and constraints - e.g. [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) has a really nice developer experience for developing and debugging tests, but testing for non-Chromium (i.e. not Chrome or Edge) browsers is limited to Firefox and still in [beta](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/launching-browsers.html#Firefox-Browsers-beta).

Comment: I would suggest reframing your question in terms of context, problems, and alternatives you have tried so far, so people can add their experiences and, thus, help you to make more informed decisions.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

## Jest

Jest is generally the test framework used with react.

A blog on e2e testing with Selenium and Jest is at

https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/jest-tutorial-for-selenium-javascript-testing-with-examples/

Another is
https://blog.evantahler.com/testing-javascript-applications-with-selenium-async-await-and-jest-7580ed074f2b

*"Jest is an awesome test framework for javascript projects (and react, and other things that compile to javascript). It supports parallel testing, watching & retrying, mocking, snapshotting… all the tools I was missing coming from Rails, the gold-standard for TDD frameworks. It turns out that some wonderful person has already done the heavy lifting to make a full-featured integration between Selenium and Jest… and it’s actually simple to use!"*

Comment: Thanks Micheal.
Is there any limitation of using Jest?